# Can't start mongodb server in windows 7

Tags: mongodb

I am using windows 7 64 bit laptop ,it contain 8 gb RAM ,i installed mongodb sucessfully ,while i am trying to connect the server using the "net start MongoDB" i stuck there lot? and it show service name is invalid, anyone could help me to retify this problem?

Comment: you are suppose to use "mongod" command to start mongodb server.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Show us some code and/or error message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt,
2. Navigate to where the mongodb is installed(usually at *C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin*),
3. Type `mongod` and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

From MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-mongodb) :

> **Start MongoDB.**
>
> To start MongoDB, run [`mongod.exe`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/#bin.mongod.exe). For example, from the
>   **Command Prompt**:
>
> ```
> "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"
> ```
>
> This starts the main MongoDB database process. The `waiting for
>   connections` message in the console output indicates that the
>   [`mongod.exe`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/#bin.mongod.exe) process is running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You take a look into log of console , you will see path of db (ex:C:\data\db)
Mongod not auto create folder when it not exist
You should create folder struct follow the log then run mongod.exe again. It will work.